# What does <$> mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

While reading a piece of Haskell code I came upon this: `<$>`. What does it mean in Haskell? After some google searches I remain in the dark.

Comment: This isn't the last "weird Haskell symbol" you will come across :)

Comment: FYI symbolhound (http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%24%3E+haskell) or more specifically hoogle (https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E) are useful in this situation.

Comment: It means money, more or less!

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Google is not the best search engine for Haskell. Try [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E) <del>or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%24%3E)</del><sup>†</sup>, both will point you right away [to this:](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-)

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b
```

It's merely an infix synonym for [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:fmap), so you can write e.g.

```
Prelude> (*2) <$> [1..3]
[2,4,6]
Prelude> show <$> Just 11
Just "11"
```

Like most infix functions, it is *not* built-in syntax, just a function definition. But functors are such a fundamental tool that `<$>` is found pretty much everywhere.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Hayoo has been offline for quite a while now.</sub>

Comment: The top result for "Haskell <$>" on Google is now this page, so in a sense, Google is now a perfectly good search engine in this case!

Comment: I like that you used the dagger symbol to denote that Hayoo has been dead for some time.

Comment: Why `<$>` instead of just `\`fmap\``? Backticks make things infix, and it's easier to read

Comment: @Richard there's certainly a point to be made that Haskellers tend to get a bit silly with all those hieroglyphic infix operators. However, `<$>` is so extremely common that one quickly gets the hang of it, it fits mnemonically together with the also very common `$`, and it _is_ a bit more compact and visually lean than ``‌`fmap`‌``. I disagree the latter is easier to read in larger contexts.