# Executing a transformation to the input before applying the function monad

Tags: haskell, lambda, monads

I am aware that I can use the function monad to achieve a construct like the one below (where I reuse the argument in multiple calls without explicitly referencing it):

```
compute_v0 :: String -> String
compute_v0 = do 
    x <- length -- (using the argument implicitly here)
    top <- head -- (and here)
    return (replicate x top)
```

The result of the above function for: `compute "1234"` would be `"1111"`

My question is: How would I apply a transformation to the 'hidden' argument before executing the do block (imagine I would like to append "abcd" to the list).

My first solution:

```
compute_v1 :: String -> String
compute_v1 = compute_v1' . (++ "abcd")

compute_v1' ::String -> String
compute_v1' = do 
    x <- length 
    top <- head
    return (replicate x top)
```

The result for `compute "1234"` would now be `"11111111"`. This actually gets the job done, but I would rather try to keep it defined all in one concise block of code.

The closest I could get to actually include the transformation while still keeping the style from code (v0) was this one:

```
compute_v2 :: String -> String 
compute_v2 = (++ "abcd") >>= \r -> do
    let x = length r
    let top = head r
    return $ replicate x top
```

But I still had to include a lambda, use a lot of let bindings and explicitly reference the lambda argument. Are there better ways to achieve such a construct?

Comment: `compute_v1 = liftA2 replicate length head . (++ "abcd")`

Comment: `compute_v1 = (replicate <$> length <*> head) . (++ "abcd")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all `Monad` instances also have `Functor` instances and the function instance of `Functor` has `fmap = (.)`, you can have

```
compute :: String -> String 
compute = flip fmap (++ "abcd") $ do
    x   <- length
    top <- head
    return $ replicate x top
```

Some packages (like `microlens` and `lens`) define `(<&>) = flip fmap`, allowing you to write

```
compute :: String -> String 
compute = (++ "abcd") <&> do
    x   <- length
    top <- head
    return $ replicate x top
```

There is also a [`Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html) instance for `(->)`, which gives us `(>>>) = flip (.)`. That might be slightly clearer, visually:

```
compute :: String -> String 
compute = (++ "abcd") >>> do
    x   <- length
    top <- head
    return $ replicate x top
```

Comment: I'd not use `fmap` when it is `(.)` in disguise. I'd use `flip (.) (++"abcd")` or `(. (++"abcd"))`. (Well, to be honest, I would never write this in monadic style, but the OP seems to want to experiment with that)

Comment: @chi That's a good point, but I wanted to highlight the thought process a bit that led me to it (which was: since we are using its monadic properties, try looking at what the `Functor` instance does).

Comment: I understand. Yes, I'd agree with that process.

Comment: It completely slipped my mind that all I had to do was to actually compose the function. However, judging from all those predefined helper flip definitions, that inversion is quite common? eg: `(++ "abcd") {do block}` instead of `{do block} (++ "abcd")`

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
compute_v2 :: String -> String
compute_v2 = do
    x <- length
    top <- head
    return $ replicate x top
    <$> (++ "abcd")
```

AFAIK, the monad in question is called the *Reader monad*, and it's also a `Functor`.

```
*Q46393211> compute_v2 "1234"
"11111111"
*Q46393211> compute_v2 "71"
"777777"
```

Comment: @chi No parse error with the code in a module loaded in GHCi. I haven't tried to 'really' compile it...

Comment: I like these "simple" Haskell questions and answers, they always make my head spin in no time. My current understanding of this: `<$>` is the infix operator of `fmap` (looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286376/what-does-mean-in-haskell)). Anything on the left of it would be a function `a->b`, the right the `f a`. So this is a function seen as a functor? For the `do` block itself, this is the `List` monad because strings are lists of chars?

Comment: @StefanHanke No, it's the function monad (and function functor) all the way. The type of the expressions to the right of the `<-`s are function types, which is one way you can tell that it is the function monad instance being used. The parsing is a bit weird here (in my opinion), but it seems to parse as `compute_vs = (do { ... do block code here ...}) <$> (++ "abcd")`. I would personally put the parens in explicitly, if I had something like that.

Comment: You could also write it as `compute_vs = doBody <$> (++ "abcd")  where doBody = do { ... do code here ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

[`MonadReader` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) has the method `local` for this, and `(->) r` is an instance, so

```
import Control.Monad.Reader (local)

compute_v3 ::String -> String
compute_v3 = local (++ "abcd") $ do 
    x <- length 
    top <- head
    return (replicate x top)
```

should work (can't test at the moment).