# How to deal with a list of 'Maybe [values]' in Haskell?

Tags: dictionary, haskell, functional-programming, lisp, option-type

I tryied to adapt some exercises of the excelent book "Land of Lisp" of Conrad Barski in order to learn Haskell. The idea is to make a simple text game engine.

Concretely I tried :

```
type Clau = String
type Descripcio = String
type Valors = [String]

-- NOTE : Ideas of types http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses
data Lloc = Lloc String String String deriving (Show) 
llocSituacio :: Lloc -> String  
llocSituacio (Lloc situacio _ _ ) = situacio  
llocDireccio :: Lloc -> String
llocDireccio (Lloc _ direccio _) = direccio
llocPas :: Lloc -> String
llocPas ( Lloc _ _ pas) = pas

nodes :: [(Clau,Descripcio)]
nodes = [("living-room","you are in the living-room. a wizard is snoring loudly on the couch.")
           ,("garden","you are in a beautiful garden. there is a well in front of you.")
           , ("attic", "you are in the attic. there is a giant welding torch in the corner.")]

edges :: [([Char], [Lloc])]
edges = [ ("living-room", [(Lloc "garden"  "west" "door"), ( Lloc "attic" "upstairs" "ladder") ])
        , ("attic", [(Lloc "living-room"  "east"  "door")])
        , ("garden", [(Lloc "living-room" "east"  "door")])]

describePath :: Lloc -> String  
describePath  e = "There is " ++ llocPas e ++ " going " ++ llocDireccio e ++ " from here."
```

At first, it seems that works well. For example:

```
*TextGame> describePath (Lloc "living-room"  "east"  "door")
"There is door going east from here."
```

But when I try to apply the function to the list I got this error:

```
situacio = "garden"
map (describePath) (lookup situacio edges)



<interactive>:2:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected **type ‘[Maybe Lloc]’**
                  with actual **type ‘Maybe [Lloc]’**
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(lookup situacio edges)’
      In the expression: map (describePath) (lookup situacio edges)
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = map (describePath) (lookup situacio edges)
```

The error is clear, but I do not manage to solve it. I want to parse the list of Maybe's values and print the path with the function describePath that works well:

Any ideas?  Also, if somebody wants to share alternatives or feel that this code could be more in Haskell style, please feel free to talk about it.

Comment: Perhaps this old answer is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375483/operating-on-a-return-from-a-maybe-that-contains-just/3375712#3375712

Comment: it's [tag:map-function], not [tag:map].

Answer (score 5):

There might be some more advanced library helpers, but I think you should first learn how to handle `Maybe`s in the most basic (and general) way: use pattern matching.

```hs
case lookup situacio edges of
   Nothing   -> [] -- not found, how do you want to handle this case?
   Just locs -> map describePath locs
```

Oftentimes, one wants instead to rewrap the result in another `Maybe`, e.g.:

```
case lookup situacio edges of
   Nothing   -> Nothing -- not found
   Just locs -> Just (map describePath locs)
```

and in such case, we can use a library helper function to shorten the code:

```
map describePath <$> lookup situacio edges
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! It works perfectly! But I realized that I do not fully understand the operator <$>, it is different that fmap right !? It includes the pattern that you pointed out !? This is exactly the difference ?!

Comment: @Mandorman `f <$> x` is exactly `fmap f x` for the `Maybe` functor: it applies `f` "under" a `Just`, and leaves `Nothing` as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot chi, it works perfectly. I just made a new function:

```
describePaths situacio edges = case lookup situacio edges of
    Nothing -> []
    Just locs -> map describePath locs
```

.. and works pretty well:

```
*TextGame> situacio = "living-room"
*TextGame> describePaths situacio edges
["There is door going west from here.","There is ladder going upstairs from here."]
```

But I see that I do not fully understand the <$> operator. I follow the comments of : [What does <$> mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286376/what-does-mean-in-haskell/37286470)

So I follow the suggestion : https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C$%3E

This is call a Functor:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b
```

That actually is exactly the same as fmap:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It seems that are the same:

```
*TextGame> (*2) <$> [1..3]
[2,4,6]
*TextGame> fmap (*2) [1..3]
[2,4,6]
```

But, actually they are different:

```
*TextGame> map describePath <$> lookup situacio edges
Just ["There is door going west from here.","There is ladder going upstairs from here."]
*TextGame> fmap (describePath) (lookup situacio edges)

<interactive>:30:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Lloc]’ with ‘Lloc’
      Expected type: Maybe Lloc
        Actual type: Maybe [Lloc]
        ....
```

Could someone put a little more light on it ? I do not fully understand why 'fmap (describePath) (lookup situacio edges)' do not work?
(I am playing with Maybe's and Just's but ...)

Comment: You removed `map` from the last example, the correct translation is `fmap (map describePath) (lookup situacio edges)`. The `fmap` here handles the `Maybe`, the `map` handles the list in `[Lloc]`.

Comment: Oh, I see! I  catched the idea now!. Thank you a lot!